# What to do if anemone themes won’t disable - Electra Jailbreak

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia, tweaks

I installed an Anemone theme from Cydia called “iPhone X Theme” to get the dock from the iPhone X on my iPhone 6s, but it didn’t look very good, so I disabled the theme and deleted it, but the dock still didn’t go back to normal. Here’s what it looks like right now. My clock app also got messed up

[image: my dock rn]

[image: clock no bg]

Comment: It would be great if you could remove the answer from the question and add it as an answer.  This would help others who could have the same issue.  See [answer] for tips.

Comment: Answer removed from question text, please post as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, all I did was disable all the themes on anemone, then restart my device. After then, I just reran the jailbreak, and everything went back to normal!